# Bit field extract with struct and endianness in C

Tags: c, endianness

I  need to clarify how the endianness affects the bit extract field in a C struct.

The following struct declares the rtp header:

```
typedef struct {
 #if BYTE_ORDER == BIG_ENDIAN
    unsigned int version:2; /* protocol version */
    unsigned int p:1;       /* padding flag */
    unsigned int x:1;       /* header extension flag */
    unsigned int cc:4;      /* CSRC count */
    unsigned int m:1;       /* marker bit */
    unsigned int pt:7;      /* payload type */
#else
   unsigned int cc:4;      /* CSRC count */
   unsigned int x:1;       /* header extension flag */
   unsigned int p:1;       /* padding flag */
   unsigned int version:2; /* protocol version */
   unsigned int pt:7;      /* payload type */
   unsigned int m:1;       /* marker bit */
#endif
  unsigned int seq:16;    /* sequence number */
  uint32_t ts;        /* timestamp */
  uint32_t ssrc;      /* synchronization source */
  uint32_t csrc[0];       /* optional CSRC list */
} rtp_hdr_t;
```

Due to the fact that endianess affect the byte ordering in memory, I hardly undestand why the struct is defined in this way in little endian architecture

Thank you

Comment: C++ variables that you operate on are always going to behave as big endian. If you do bit manipulation on a `int` it is going to be the same result regardless of whether the underlying architecture is big or little (or even mixed) endian. Only when you export/import data from/to byte arrays outside your program do you need to care.

Comment: I don't think such `#ifdef` is necessary at all. The author of that code probably missed to use the [htonx()/ntohx()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924598/understanding-htonl-and-ntohl) functions to deal with the endianess in a transparent way in the c / c++ code.

Comment: this question is about C++, not C.  Please remove the 'c' tag

Comment: @user3629249 How is that question specific for c++ only?

Comment: The name/title of the question.  The first sentence of the question.

Comment: [c] tagged removed as OP's stated interest here and history are only about C++.  The rules about bit fields tend to be arcane - so  focusing on  one language adds clarity. -- Oh well, OP has edited and  narrowed to C only now.

Comment: Bit fields are ANSI C and there is nothing in the question that is C++ specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endianness can also affect bits, not just bytes, however the only time you typically see the effects is in a bitfield.  This is one reason why the ordering of bitfields in a struct, and which byte offsets they live at, is implementation defined.

Looking at this definition, it seems to imply that for the given implementation that bitfields are physically placed in order on big endian systems and in the reverse order for each byte on a little endian system.

In particular, the first 4 bitfields occupy 8 bits and the next 2 bitfields occupy 8 bits.  So in the case of little endian the order of the first 4 bitfields are reversed with each other and the last 2 bitfields are reversed with each other.

Code like this is common in system header files.  For example, /usr/include/netinet/in.h on Linux contains the following struct to model an IP header:

```
struct iphdr
  {
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    unsigned int ihl:4;
    unsigned int version:4;
#elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    unsigned int version:4;
    unsigned int ihl:4;
#else
# error "Please fix <bits/endian.h>"
#endif
    u_int8_t tos;
    u_int16_t tot_len;
    u_int16_t id;
    u_int16_t frag_off;
    u_int8_t ttl;
    u_int8_t protocol;
    u_int16_t check;
    u_int32_t saddr;
    u_int32_t daddr;
    /*The options start here. */
  };
```

Presumably, the idea is that a buffer containing a raw network packet can use `memcpy` to copy the bytes into an instance of this struct (or just have a pointer to this struct point to the buffer, if it's aligned correctly) to simplify serialization / deserialization.  You'll still need to call the `htonx`/`ntohx` family of function to properly read integer fields occupying more than one byte however.

Comment: I don't see the benefit doing so at all tho. There already (POSIX) functions available, to deal with the network byte order correctly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  This is dealing with bit order, not byte order.  I'm not sure if OP's code comes from a system header file, but the definition of `struct iphdr` in /usr/include/netinet/ip.h does the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I think the only reasonable interpretation is that the original coder wanted to ensure that the order of the bits would be the same regardless of endian-ness.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the endianness issues, you have no way of knowing where each bitfield will be.

Per [**6.7.2 Type specifiers**, paragraph 11 of the C Standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p11):

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit- field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, **whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified**.

If you need to know exactly where a bit is in your data, use of bitfields is **entirely** non-portable, even between different compilers on the same platform.