# How do you concatenate several long int into a char array?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am working on a project in my Arduino, where I want to send several values to a destination through a very slow radio link.

I need to send **7 `long` variables, that are 4 bytes each**. So rather than converting them to hex strings for up to 64 bytes of data, I would love to store them all in an array, `char payload[32];`

I tried doing something like this:

```
long first = 5000;
long second = 10000;
char payload[8];
long* pointer;

pointer = &payload[0];
*pointer = first;
pointer = &payload[4];
*pointer = second;
```

But I get hit by a conversion error.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Why not simply `uint32_t payload[7]`?

Answer (score 3):

A `char*` is not compatible with a `long*`, so you need an explicit type-cast when assigning your `pointer` variable, eg:

```cpp
long first = 5000;
long second = 10000;
char payload[sizeof(long)*2];
long* pointer;

pointer = reinterpret_cast<long*>(&payload[0]);
*pointer = first;
pointer = reinterpret_cast<long*>(&payload[4]);
*pointer = second;
```

Alternatively (and safer), use `memcpy()` instead, eg:

```cpp
long first = 5000;
long second = 10000;
char payload[sizeof(long)*2];

memcpy(&payload[0], &first, sizeof(first));
memcpy(&payload[4], &second, sizeof(second));
```

That being said, if you want to ensure a 32-bit integer is used for transmission, you really should use `int32_t` instead of `long`.  `long` is not 32-bit on all platforms, though it is on Arduino (who is to say that can never change in the future, though).  You should always use fixed-width types when you need to use specific bit sizes.

Comment: Less and less important these days, but also keep an eye out for [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) differences between the source and destination. [`ntohl` and `htonl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924598/understanding-htonl-and-ntohl) may come in handy.